# How to persist custom options on WYSIWYG Trix Editor while editing (Ruby on Rails, Actiontext)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix, actiontext

**I am creating a Rails website with a WYSIWYG, using Trix and actiontext. I am using Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 5.2.3.**

**Issue:** when I implement custom edition (i.e, adding a text color red) it works perfectly at the creation (CRUD: new), displays perfectly when rendering it (CRUD: show), but when I try to edit the text, my custom styling is not displayed in my editor in the edit view, and the span that trix added to the rich text is not present in the client DOM (CRUD: edit).

As it renders in the Show view, I confirm that my custom edition persist in the database.

I suppose this is a sanitizing issue. 
I previously had this issue with the show, so I added the style attribute to the Rails sanitizer allowed attributes.

My trix customizer looks like this to add a red option:

```
// Attributes definition :
Trix.config.textAttributes.red = { 
    style: { color: "red" },
  parser: function(element) {
    return element.style.color === "red"
  },
  inheritable: true
 }

addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {  
  var buttonHTML = '<button type="button" data-trix-attribute="red">RED</button>'


    event.target.toolbarElement.
    querySelector(".trix-button-group.trix-button-group--text-tools").
        insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", buttonHTML)
})
```

It works well when used in the editor (option in the toolbar is functional in both edit and new view).

Also, to display correctly in the show view, I added a Rails initializer to allow style attributes :

```rb
Rails::Html::Sanitizer.white_list_sanitizer.allowed_attributes.add 'style'
```

The issue is, when I go to the edit view, the red style applied previously does not render anymore. Notice that I use exactly the same _form.html.erb for both create and edit view :

```rb
<%= simple_form_for([@owner, @article] , url: @action[:url], method: @action[:method]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.rich_text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Don't hesitates if you need more details.
Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Use rgb format:

```
Trix.config.textAttributes.color = {
  style: { color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' },
  parser: (element) => element.style.color === 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
  inheritable: true
}
```